# Accessing ASP.net application hosted on one server from multiple machines on the network at the same time

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have designed a voting application (Students will vote their department teachers) for my college. I have hosted the site on a server and there is no problem in accessing the site from other machines on the network. But when some one is accessing a database table (teacher table for voting) and at the same time somebody else is trying to access the same table from another machine, the problem arises. 
Suppose the 1st user is voting teacher no 2. At the same time 2nd user completes voting teacher 1 and when he tries to get the 2nd teacher by clicking next. But the system return the 3rd teacher and so on.

What should I do to solve this problem?

coding of the voting.aspx.cs page

```
public partial class voting : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Database=dkd; User Id=root; Password=;");
    static string tid;
    static int i;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["dept"] = "Physics";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            i = 2;
            loadTeacher(i);
        }

}
void loadTeacher(int x)
{
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from teachers where department='" + Session["dept"].ToString() + "' order by tid asc", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    int n=ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    //if (n == 0)
    //{
    //    x++;
    //    loadTeacher(x);
    //}
    if (x >= n)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (n > 0)
    {
        tid = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        lbtid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        lbname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        lbdept.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].ItemArray[2].ToString();
        lbage.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].ItemArray[3].ToString();
        lbsex.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].ItemArray[4].ToString();
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Photos/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].ItemArray[5].ToString();
    }
}
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("insert into rating values(null,'" + lbtid.Text + "','" + lbdept.Text + "','" + ddq1.Text + "','" + ddq2.Text + "','" + ddq3.Text + "','" + ddq4.Text + "','" + ddq5.Text + "','" + ddq6.Text + "','" + ddq7.Text + "','" + ddq8.Text + "','" + ddq9.Text + "','" + ddq10.Text + "')", con);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int score;
    score = Int32.Parse(ddq1.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq2.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq3.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq4.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq5.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq6.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq7.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq8.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq9.Text) + Int32.Parse(ddq10.Text);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select total from score where teacherid='" + lbtid.Text + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    int tot = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]);
    tot = tot + score;
    MySqlCommand com1 = new MySqlCommand("Update score set total='" + tot + "' where teacherid ='" + lbtid.Text + "'", con);
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    clearfields();
    i++;
    loadTeacher(i);
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like a bad design. No idea how to help without seeing some relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aptly-named `static int i`, which holds the "current teacher index" is static, or shared between all visitors in the same AppDomain.

Don't make it static, save it in the session.

Comment: That works. Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

change static fieds to something like this:

```
    private int? _teacherIndex;
    protected int TeacherIndex
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_teacherIndex.HasValue)
            {
                var iObject = Session["_teacherIndex"];
                var i = 0;
                if (iObject != null)
                {
                    int.TryParse(iObject.ToString(), out i);
                }
                _teacherIndex = i;
            }
            return _teacherIndex.Value;
        }
        set { Session["_teacherIndex"] = value; }
    }
```